# How to use these Jython functions in Python?

Tags: python, image, jython, jes

I just want to know that how can I use Jython functions such as below in Python.

```
makeEmptyPicture(width,height)
show(pic)
setAllPixelsToAColor(pic, red)
```

When I use these functions in Python, it gives me an error that the name `makeEmptyPicture` is not defined.

What should I do?
Do I have to install some library in my Python or is something else required?

Comment: Where did those methods come from? JVM?

Comment: Apparently they are part of the [Jython Environment for Students](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mediacomp-jes/) from Georgia Tech. These are not part of the standard Jython distribution. These libraries appear to be mainly built on top of core Java libraries, so it will not be practical to use them from standard Python.

Comment: So I have to download Jython in my OS then I am able to execute these functions?

Comment: You will never be able to use these from your ordinary Python interpreter. If you install Georgia Tech's custom Jython package and run your code with that, the functions should be available. I've never used any of this myself.

Comment: Will you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: JES is on GitHub. Instructions for installing and running are here: https://github.com/gatech-csl/jes.

Comment: As @mzjn says, there are instructions on the sites we linked. We can't walk you through every step -- that's not what this site is for. If you have specific problems along the way, you can ask narrow questions specifically about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I actually got the answer.

First, download the JES 5.02 from the below link depending on your OS and Java installed or not.

```
https://github.com/gatech-csl/jes/releases
```

And then run the following functions. Because the functions which I use in this program like makeEmptyPicture, pickAColor etc are basically the JES functions and will not be compiled by python compiler except this JES.